# scope定義でcreated_atの日時によりレコードのカウント方法を変えて集計する方法は？

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord, sql, postgresql

railsのウェブアプリでデータベースの中に記事レコード(Post)があり「その中で人気がありかつ新しいものが上」という条件のscopeを定義しようと考えています。
PostはActsAsVotableでLikeボタンを押すことでLike数をvotesで集計できるようになっています。また記事ごとにアクセス数をposts.view_countに保存しています。

今は「Like数 * 10 + 記事のアクセス数の数値が高いものから（記事の作成日が１ヶ月以内）」という条件で並べています。

`scope :featuring, -> { joins(:votes).where('posts.created_at > ?', Time.now - 1.month).group('posts.id').order('(count(votes.id)*10 + posts.view_count) DESC, posts.id DESC') }`

この方法ですとLike数がゼロの記事はアクセス数があってもscopeに含まれません。かつ本当に入れたい条件とは少し異なっております。
本当は
　「１週間以内のLike数 * 100 + 1ヶ月以内のLike数 *10 + 記事のアクセス数の数値が高いものから（記事の作成日が２ヶ月以内）」　という条件にしたいです。
どのようにすればいいのでしょうか？
できればscopeで記述したいのですが、無理ならクラス・メソッドでもかまわないと考えています。
方法はありますでしょうか？
データベースはPostgreSQLです。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 「１週間以内のLike数 * 100 + 1ヶ月以内のLike数 *10 + 記事のアクセス数の数値が高いものから（記事の作成日が２ヶ月以内）」　という条件にしたいです。

たぶん、こんな感じかなーと思います。

```
scope :featuring, -> {
  select("posts.*")
  .joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN votes ON votes.post_id = posts.id") # 実際のテーブル構造に合わせて変更してください
  .where('posts.created_at > ?', 2.months.ago)
  .group('posts.id')
  .order(<<-ORDER_SQL)
( SUM(
   CASE WHEN votes.created_at > current_timestamp + '-7 days' THEN 100
        WHEN votes.created_at > current_timestamp + '-31days' THEN 10
        ELSE 0 END
  )
  + posts.view_count
) DESC, posts.id DESC
  ORDER_SQL
}
```

全く同じ環境で動作確認することはできないので、エラーが出た場合は適宜修正してください。

Comment: できました！ありがとうございます。
最初のところだけjoins(:votes)ではじめましたが、後は回答のとおりでした。
`.order(<<-ORDER_SQL)`のようなテクニックを知らなかったので、勉強になりました。

Comment: 良かったです！ただ、joins(:votes)だと、likeがゼロ件の場合にデータが出てこないんじゃないかなと思います。(INNER JOINで結合されると思うので) 念のため確認してみてください。（最初の回答ではjoinsをjoinと書き間違えていたので修正しました。）

Comment: まさにおっしゃっる通りです。Junichi Itoさんのコードで成功したのですが、結果をみてLikeゼロは表示させない仕様に変更しました。ご回答に関しては完璧でした。ありがとうございます。